# Keras custom lambda layer: how to normalize / scale the output

Tags: keras, neural-network, normalization, loss-function, normalize

I am struggling with scaling the output of a lambda layer. The code is as follows:
My X_train is 100*15*24 and Y_train is 100*1 (the network consists with a LSTM layer + Dense layer)

```
input_shape=(timesteps, num_feat)
data_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_layer")
lstm1 = LSTM(10, name="lstm_layer")(data_input)
dense1 = Dense(4, activation="relu", name="dense1")(lstm1)
dense2 = Dense(1, activation = "custom_activation_1", name = "dense2")(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(1, activation = "custom_activation_2", name = "dense3")(dense1) 
#dense 2 and 3 has customed activation function with range the REAL LINE (so I need to normalize it)


## custom lambda layer/ loss function ##
def custom_layer(new_input):

    add_input = new_input[0]+new_input[1]
    
    #below three lines are where problem occurs that makes the program does not work
    ###############################################
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(add_input)
    normalized = scaler.transform(add_input)
    ###############################################
    return normalized

lambda_layer = Lambda(custom_layer, name="lambda_layer")([dense2, dense3])

model = Model(inputs=data_input, outputs=lambda_layer) 
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=216)
```

How can I normalize the output of *lambda_layer* properly? Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Scikit transformers would work in Lambda layers. If you're only interested in getting the normalized output w.r.t the data passed in, you can do,

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf


timesteps = 3
num_feat = 12
input_shape=(timesteps, num_feat)
data_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_layer")
lstm1 = LSTM(10, name="lstm_layer")(data_input)
dense1 = Dense(4, activation="relu", name="dense1")(lstm1)
dense2 = Dense(1, activation = "custom_activation_1", name = "dense2")(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(1, activation = "custom_activation_2", name = "dense3")(dense1) 
#dense 2 and 3 has customed activation function with range the REAL LINE (so I need to normalize it)


## custom lambda layer/ loss function ##
def custom_layer(new_input):

    add_input = new_input[0]+new_input[1]
    
    normalized = (add_input - tf.reduce_min(add_input, axis=0, keepdims=True))/(tf.reduce_max(add_input, axis=0, keepdims=True) - tf.reduce_max(add_input, axis=0, keepdims=True))
    
    return normalized

lambda_layer = Lambda(custom_layer, name="lambda_layer")([dense2, dense3])

model = Model(inputs=data_input, outputs=lambda_layer) 
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @thushv89    It works! Can I ask you one follow-up question: the reason to use tf.reduce_max is that "add_input" is a two dimension array so I cannot just use min(), which is supposed to be applied to a 1-d input? So when we want to apply min/ max to an array with dimension greater than one, we should use tf.reduce_min/max, is this correct? (By the way, I think there is a typo - the denominator part of "normalized" should be tf.reduce_max - tf.reduce_min)

Comment: @Doi_Ann, you can use reduce_min/max on a 1D vector, nD vector with multiple axis or nD vector with a single axis. It's quite versatile. The reason I used axis=0 is because that's how the Scikit minmax scaler does it. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Comment: thank you for your reply! it helped us to build custom layers in keras and specifically minmax